# Dynamo DB CLI Import CSV entries to Dynamo DB table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a usecase to import CSV entries to Dynamo DB table , however I tried the JSON way and it's working , unable to get this working with CSV

`aws dynamodb batch-write-item --request-items file://itementries.json`

````
{
    "TABLE-NAME": [
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "fname": {
                        "S": "Jon"
                    },
                    "lname": {
                        "S": "Doe"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the CLI and BatchWriteItem to import CSV, only using DDB-JSON.

If you want to import CSV, then you first need to upload the data to S3 and use the `ImportTable` API:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/import-table.html